# Java regex, capture multiple groups

Tags: java, regex

Using example code on SO I found, and a string I'm searching, I'm trying to capture groups of aircraft classes and their seats. The input file has the aircraft configuration in the form  J28W36Y156 which means 28 J (business) class seats, 36 W (premium economy seats) and 156 Y (economy) seats.

The Java code I'm using is as follows:

```
    s = "J12W28Y156";
    patternStr = "(\\w\\d+)+";
    p = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        int count = m.groupCount();
        System.out.println("group count is "+count);
        for(int i=1;i<=count;i++){
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
        }
    }
```

The regex seems to only capture the LAST class seat config ie. Y156. How do I get this regex to capture all of the class/seat combos in multiple groups. Does this have something to do with it being a 'greedy' match I need to specifiy?
I would like the output to be something like an array eg.

{J12, W28, Y156}

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first mistake is a wrong interpretation of `\w`. Here is what javadoc says:

`\w A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]`

It means that `\w` captures both letters and digits. So, in your case taking in consideration that letters are always in upper case I'd use the following pattern:

`[A-Z]\d+`

Now it will capture the first place marker. So you should implement the loop yourself:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    String place = m.group(1);
    // A12, W28 etc is here
}
```

Comment: Thankyou AlexR - I misunderstood the \w pattern...works perfectly now, thanks again.

Comment: Actually, the real problem with the regex is the final plus sign.  `"(\\w\\d+)+"` captures `J12` in group #1, then it captures `W28` in group #1 (overwriting the `J12`), then it overwrites *that* with `Y156`.  The reason your code works is because you removed the final plus sign from the regex AND used `while (find())` to iterate over the matches.  The `\w` was incorrect, but it wasn't causing the problem--it wasn't even a contributing factor. :-/